# left sidebar with menu

Tags: theming

I have cloned bartik so that I can adjust it to my needs.
Basically, I want a left sidebar containing the main menu which slides up over the main content if used on a small screen.  The "normal" theme has the sidebar sliding down and under, which is no use when the menu is in it.
I've tried editing the page.tpl.php by moving the sidebar statement up above the content, and just below the breadcrumbs.    This shows successfully on a mobile screen, however the sidebar disappears on a pc and slides under the main content.
Do I just attempt to fix it all with css now, or is there something else I need to address?

Comment: Which Drupal version?

Comment: Based on your question, I think you will have to fix this with css as menu are showing for mobile but not desktop that means it is css issue.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the block in the page.tpl.php was the correct move to make.
The layout.css had to be altered by splitting out many of the grouped items to specifically target the blocks wanted before the desktop arrangement was correct.
An important thing is to clear the cache after making each correction, otherwise it will appear not to have taken place.

A correction to this is that the change only works for minified screens. The desktop screen was corrupted instead, and a solution is now required for that.